# Как ограничить удаление похожих записей?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Пишу игровой проект. Возник  такой вопрос. Есть сумка с вещами. В сумку вещи попадают по своему айди. Но если две шмотки одиниковые лежат, то айдишки у них так же одинаковые. И когда человек хочет продать одну шмотку, то вторая продается автоматически без начисления денег игроку.
Как в SQL сделать удаление только первого вхождения по условию? А второе оставить?

```
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Пробовал такое, но вы выходит). Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: В таблице обязано быть поле, уникальное для записи (первичный ключ). Создайте, Удаление выполняйте именно по значению первичного ключа.

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас логика невереная. Таблица в БД "Сумка" может выглядеть так:

```
unique_id   player_id   item_id
```

для реалиазации связи многие ко многим.

Вот тут как раз `id` будет уникальный и неважно, что у человека может быть три пары перчаток в сумке. Для продажи надо как раз изначально смотреть на эту таблицу и далее джойнить таблицу с `items` чтобы паосмотреть её цену. А удалять нужно как раз из таблицы со связями, описанной выше по уникальному идентификатору.

Comment: Уже сделал. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Да... Тоже считаю что тут сама структура таблицы более чем нарушена, и этот ответ считаю более полноценным! Алексей совершенно прав, что первичный ключ более чем решит проблему, хотя то не касается HighLoad игр, там первичный ключ равен смерти инвентаря. Из опыта CCP Games когда они юзали GUID, у них на девлаб была целая группа статей по оптимизации инвентарей. В конце концов они дошли до ссылок на сумку X... Но в их масштабах это более чем рациональное решение...

Comment: Они давали уникальный ID каждой сумке каждого игрока, исходя из уникального ID сумки брали уникальные ID предметов, и обращались по целой цепочке связей. И всё равно в 2016м году, был огромный скандал, когда на рынке появилось 12% клонированных предметов.

Answer (score 0):

Ну во первых зачем там order by? Если есть вопросы, то задавай в коментах дополню. Укажи что за версия MySQL или MariaDB они хоть по синтаксису и похожи, но разделены стеной размером в несколько лет.

```
DELETE FROM `bag` WHERE `id_user` = ? AND `id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```